# Ceiling date (Similar to R's ceiling_date) in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Suppose I have the following pandas dataframe,

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

df = pd.DataFrame([[201901, 'Value1'], [201902, 'Value2'], [201707, 'Value3], columns=['Col1', 'Col2'])
╔════════╦═════════╗
║  Col1  ║  Col2   ║
╠════════╬═════════╣ 
║ 201901 ║ Value 1 ║
║ 201902 ║ Value 2 ║
║ 201707 ║ Value 3 ║
╚════════╩═════════╝
```

And I want the first column to be like this (I want the last day of every month):

```
╔════════════╦═════════╗
║    Col1    ║  Col2   ║
╠════════════╬═════════╣
║ 2019-01-31 ║ Value 1 ║
║ 2019-02-28 ║ Value 2 ║
║ 2017-07-31 ║ Value 3 ║
╚════════════╩═════════╝
```

So, to acchieve that I've tried the following:

```
next_month = {'01':'02', '02':'03', 
              '03':'04', '04':'05', 
              '05':'06', '06':'07', 
              '07':'08', '08':'09', 
              '09':'10', '10':'11', 
              '11':'12', '12':'01'}

df = df['Col1'].apply(lambda x: str(int(str(x)[:4])+1) + next_month[str(x)[-2:] 
                      if str(x)[-2:] else str(x)[:4] + next_month[str(x)[-2:]])

df['Col1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Col1'], format='%Y%m') - timedelta(days=1)
```

In that last part of the code, I'm replacing the row month for the following month, and checking if it's december adding one a year.

Is there a way to acchieve this effiently? I've tried also this but it took SO MUCH time, even more than the previous code showed.

```
df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].apply(lambda x: (x + relativedelta(months=1)) - relativedelta(days=1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use same idea in numpy for improve performance:

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df['Col1'], format='%Y%m')

df['Col11'] = (s.to_numpy().astype('datetime64[M]') +
              np.array([1], dtype='timedelta64[M]') - 
              np.array([1], dtype='timedelta64[D]'))
```

Another idea is create dictionary and [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
d = dict(zip(pd.date_range('1900', '2100', freq='MS')[:-1],
             pd.date_range('1900', '2100', freq='M')))

df['Col12'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Col1'], format='%Y%m').map(d)
print (df)
     Col1    Col2      Col11      Col12
0  201901  Value1 2019-01-31 2019-01-31
1  201902  Value2 2019-02-28 2019-02-28
2  201707  Value3 2017-07-31 2017-07-31
```

Comment: Going to try it. The code provided by me takes ~6minutos, let's see yours. Thank you!

Comment: Tried the first idea, ran faster than my code and also faster than @QuagHoang (for seconds). Just for that, I'm going to mark this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think `tseries.offsets.MonthEnd` is what you need?

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Col1'], format='%Y%m') + pd.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd(1)
```

Output:

```
0   2019-01-31
1   2019-02-28
2   2017-07-31
Name: Col1, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, that was what I needed, however, due I was looking for efficiency in the code I marked another answer as the correct one.